# C++ .EXE Crashing Unhandled exception at 0x10006454 (libmySQL.dll)

Tags: c++, mysql

I am trying to connect to an online MySQL database(Which I managed to do) but I crash after I reach "Loading map data" and I get this error when I debug:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x10006454 (libmySQL.dll) in Spitfire.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

This is the entie block of code where it would fail:

```
#ifndef _DEBUG
for (int x = 0; x < (DEF_MAPSIZE*DEF_MAPSIZE); x += (DEF_MAPSIZE*DEF_MAPSIZE)/10)
{
    //msql->Reset();
    //msql->Select("SELECT * FROM `tiles` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT %d,%d;", x, (DEF_MAPSIZE*DEF_MAPSIZE)/200);
    //msql->Fetch();

    char query[1024];
    sprintf(query, "SELECT `id`,`ownerid`,`type`,`level` FROM `tiles` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT %d,%d", x, ((DEF_MAPSIZE*DEF_MAPSIZE)/10));
    mysql_query(gserver->msql->mySQL, query);
    st_mysql_res* m_pQueryResult;
    m_pQueryResult = mysql_store_result(msql->mySQL);
    int m_iRows = (int)mysql_num_rows(m_pQueryResult);
    int m_iFields = mysql_num_fields(m_pQueryResult);
    //MYSQL_FIELD ** field = new MYSQL_FIELD*[m_iFields+1];;
    MYSQL_ROW myRow;
    mysql_field_seek(m_pQueryResult, 0);



    for (int i = 0; i < m_iRows; ++i)
    {
        myRow = mysql_fetch_row(m_pQueryResult);
        int64_t id = _atoi64(myRow[0]);
        int64_t ownerid = _atoi64(myRow[1]);
        int64_t type = _atoi64(myRow[2]);
        int64_t level = _atoi64(myRow[3]);

        //          int id = msql->GetInt(i, "id");
        //          int ownerid = msql->GetInt(i, "ownerid");
        //          int type = msql->GetInt(i, "type");
        //          int level = msql->GetInt(i, "level");
        gserver->m_map->m_tile[id].m_id = id;
        gserver->m_map->m_tile[id].m_ownerid = ownerid;
        gserver->m_map->m_tile[id].m_type = type;
        gserver->m_map->m_tile[id].m_level = level;


        if (type == NPC)
        {
            NpcCity * city = (NpcCity *)gserver->AddNpcCity(id);
            city->Initialize(true, true);
            city->m_level = level;
            city->m_ownerid = ownerid;
            gserver->m_map->m_tile[id].m_zoneid = gserver->m_map->GetStateFromID(id);
        }

        if ((id+1)%((DEF_MAPSIZE*DEF_MAPSIZE)/100) == 0)
        {
            Log("%d%%", int((double(double(id+1)/(DEF_MAPSIZE*DEF_MAPSIZE)))*double(100)));
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result(m_pQueryResult);
}

msql->Reset();
```

## else

```
//this fakes map data
for (int x = 0; x < (DEF_MAPSIZE*DEF_MAPSIZE); x += 1/*(DEF_MAPSIZE*DEF_MAPSIZE)/10*/)
{
    m_map->m_tile[x].m_id = x;
    m_map->m_tile[x].m_ownerid = -1;
    m_map->m_tile[x].m_type = rand()%11;
    m_map->m_tile[x].m_level = rand()%11;


    if ((x+1)%((DEF_MAPSIZE*DEF_MAPSIZE)/100) == 0)
    {
        Log("%d%%", int((double(double(x+1)/(DEF_MAPSIZE*DEF_MAPSIZE)))*double(100)));
    }
}
```

## endif

```
m_map->CalculateOpenTiles();
```

Would anyone have any clue as to why this happens. Also, if I may mention, it doesn't give me this error. Also to mention, when I look at my call stack it points to certain lines of code such as:

```
int m_iRows = (int)mysql_num_rows(m_pQueryResult);
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

P.S the code to output "Loading map data" is maybe tweo lines above what I copied from my code.

Comment: Are `mysql_query` and `mysql_store_result` supposed to be using different `mySQL` pointers? Unless both pointers have the same value, that could cause an issue.

Comment: You probably passed a NULL to MySQL accidentally.

Comment: @TheDark Yes they are suppose to.

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought that the mySql value passed to both functions would have to be the same for it to retrieve the result of the mysql_query call. I haven't used it though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Very much agree with @immibis.  You never NULL-test `m_pQueryResult` before using it.  I would venture that you also never checked whether your connection with the database was successful.

Comment: Also agree with @TheDark -- it makes no sense to query `gserver->msql->mySQL` and they try to store the result from `msql->mySQL`, unless those pointers are exactly the same.

Comment: @paddy I think your most likely rgiht. I am still unsure of how to fix the problem, so would you mind posting the modified code or atleast point me to a reference?

Comment: Your program seems to be using two different database connections.  It is querying one, and then requesting the query result from the other.  We don't know whether this is relevant or not. It's up to you to determine if those connections are actually the same pointer.  As for the NULL-testing, do you *really* need us to post code explaining how to check whether a pointer is NULL?

Comment: @paddy Nvm then, that explains it better.

Comment: @TheDark I updated mysql_store_result to this "m_pQueryResult = mysql_store_result(gserver->msql->mySQL);" and it still crashes still. It is inconsistent though, some times it crashes immediately after loading map and other times it crashes a little while after.